# How to erase spaces and a group of chars from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I forgot to mention one more space after `100`

i have this string `phone="+46 (0) 100 234567"` and i want to get the same number without `(0)` and the spaces.(in javascript)

final: `phone = "+46100234567"`

what i have tried so far is this:

1. `phone.replace(/[(0)]*[^0-9+]/g, '', '')` => which erases all 0's
2. `phone.replace(/\(0\)\s*/g,'')` => which erases `(0)` but keeps the spaces.

any help would be welcome.

Comment: `[(0)]` means _any character_ of `(`, `0` or `)`. Please use [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and read [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/4642212). Your second regex already erases the space after `(0)`. So put another `\s*` before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.info("+46 (0) 100 234567".replace(/\(0\)|\s/g, ''));
```

One solution is `"+46 (0) 100 234567".replace(/\(0\)|\s/g, '')`.
With the global attribute `/g` you don't need to use the `*`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
\s+|\(\d*\)
```

Replace the matches with a blank string

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KWXtiN/2)

**Explanation:**

- `\s+` - matches 1+ occurrences of a whitespace
- `|` - OR
- `\(\d*\)` - matches a `(` followed by 0+ digits followed by `)`

**CODE**

```js
const regex = /\s+|\(\d*\)/g;
const str = `+46 (0) 100 234567`;
const subst = ``;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: @Jan You have a valid point but if the test string is like `+46 () 100234567`, in that case `*` would work too. I know, this is not realistic scenario but still is handled.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
/\s*\(0\)\s*/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var phone = "+46 (0) 100234567";
phone.replace(/\s*\(0\)\s*/g,'');
```